# How to get a notification from LiveData in Android if Firebase Database changes and Fragment is not active

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-livedata

I am using the Single-Activity and Multiple-Fragments approach, and I have one fragment that has a ViewModel with LiveData. The UI always changes when there is a change in a remote database (Firebase Realtime Database). I followed steps that are described in the offical Firebase Blog (https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components.html). However, the fragment, which the LiveData and ViewModel are bound to, is not active (because I navigated to another fragment) I don't get a notification if something changes in the database.

What I would actually want is to get informed when something changes in the Firebase database no matter which fragment is active, because I would like to play a small notification sound such that the user knows that something has changed. When the fragment that is bound to the LiveData is not active, the UI should not be updated, but the notification sound should be played.

My question is whether this is possible with LiveData (Mutable LiveData) in combindation with Firebase Realtime-Database and if so, how can I do this? I think by default, LiveData only notifies and executes code, if the fragment is active.

**Reminder**: Any idea how to do that? I'll appreciate every comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing that depending on the desired behavior. If you want to be notified whenever data changes and your application is active you can do the following:

- Ensure that you have a data or repository class that is scoped to the lifecycle of the application.  Since you are using single activity architecture, you can also use an activity scoped view model.
- Firebase already provides you a way of being notified whenever data changes  through `onDataChange()` [listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data).  You should listen to these changes in you data/repo/viewmodel class and react to changes whenever your data changes.
- If you have the scoping done correctly, you'll be notified regardless of which fragment you are on.  You can then react to those changes (play sound) as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean with "Ensure that you have a data or repository class that is scoped to the lifecycle of the application.". Actually I have a Fragement, a ViewModel and a LiveData class. Within the LiveData class the `onDataChange` method is called. Whenever something changes in Firebase, the `onChanged` method is called in the Fragment. This works quite well but only if the Fragment is the currently displayed Fragment. When there is another Fragment being displayed (in the same App) I don't get any notification. I think this is a disadvantage of LiveData

Comment: Any comments on my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you. I think that maybe the problem is that I use LiveData and I am not sure whether I can fix this problem with using LiveData. LiveData has the drawback that it is only active when the corresponding fragment is active as far as I understood. This is not what I want. I would like to have something like LiveData without the disadvantage that it is not active when the Fragment is not shown. However, depending on the status of the Fragment, the UI should be updated or not whereas the sound should be always played.

Comment: Hello, you mentioned that your viewmodel is tied to your fragment, therefore when you navigate to a different fragment, your viewmodel goes away and you no longer receive updates.  What you want is something along the lines of having a view model that outlives your fragment.  You can define this view model on activity level and share it across fragments.  This lab should give you a good idea of how to share a view model across fragments https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-shared-viewmodel#0

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. Unfortunately the lab you posted used Kotlin and I don't use Kotlin (and don't understand it). Furthermore, the shared viewmodel is quite complex and advanced. I would like to have something more basic. This is why I would like to try your first suggested approach "Ensure that you have a data or repository class that is scoped to the lifecycle of the application. ". What do you mean by scoping and how can I do that? Shall I use a LiveData class for the whole Activity?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments. Any comments to my last comment? I'll highly apprciate any further comment from you.

Comment: Any comments to my last comments?

Comment: I would recommend the shared view model one.  If you are familiar with the singleton pattern.  You can create a singleton class that contains your firebase code and refer to that class from your view models. I've been busy with work so I may not have time to create a full example for it but singleton pattern is pretty common in java so you should be able to find examples for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. Actually I am not familiar at all with the singleton pattern and I think the shared view model sounds quite complex (I had a look into it). Can I not just define a ViewModel and LiveData for the whole activity or any other easy solution. Basically everything works fine with LiveData and the ViewModel, the only problem is that when the Fragment is not active, nothing happens. It should just play a simple sound when something changes, so it should not be such a big deal with complex design patterns and shared view models

Comment: You can define the view model on the activity level and just access it in the fragments https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#java

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I would leaf the ViewModel of the Fragment as it is and define a separate ViewModel and LiveData for the Activity class that only plays this sound. This way there will be no need to access anything from the fragments and I don't need any additional complex pattern like a shared ViewModel or a Singleton. Of course the downside is that I have to write some boilerplate code to access the same Table in the Firebase Database.

Comment: Is there not something similar as LiveData in Android without the disadvantage that it only is doing something when the fragment is active? Ideally the class would do different things depending on whether the fragment is active or not. If the Fragment is active and something changes in the Firebase database, the UI should be updated in addition to the sound being played. If the Fragment is not active and the Firebase database changes, the sound should still be played. So the object should be Lifecycle aware of the activity and fragment. Unfortunately LiveData is not